# Using a custom Docker path in IBM Cloud private

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to install IBM Cloud private (1.2) on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have docker configured via my `daemon.json` to a custom path.

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 

{ 
   "graph" : "/some/other/path"
}
```

Installation succeeded, but network related pods failed to start.
Without my custom path, install works great. The network pods started correctly.
How can I leverage custom docker paths configured via `daemon.json` in IBM Cloud private installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a kubelet of IBM Cloud private is run in the container, and the `/var/lib/docker` is mounted on the container. The kubelet will not be able to find the path you defined in `daemon.json`.

You can bind mount `/var/lib/docker` on your specified path without setting `daemon.json`. Or you need to uninstall the cluster, set `enable_external_kubelet: true` in `config.yaml` and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Cloud private works in the container as Jian Qiu said. You can try to create a symlink ( original path - > your custom path )